# How to create a macro variable consuming datas from another dataset replacing from / to?

Tags: sas

I'm looking for a way to do a replace a string of dataset 1, using content from dataset 2.

I have field "Address " on dataset 1 :

```
data dataset;
infile datalines;
input Address  $ B $;
datalines;
Indonesia St 
Canada Av near from USA St
Japan St
Cingapure Av
;
run;
```

I have a dataset that willl be use as FROM/TO:

```
data dataset;
infile datalines;
input A  $ B $;
datalines;
St Street
Av Avenue
;
run;
```

I expect return something like that:

```
Indonesia Street
Canada Avenue near from USA Street
Japan Street
Cingapure Avenue
```

Does anyone knows how can I solve it?

Comment: What does the macro variable referenced in your subject line have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution to this problem - which has many possible ones - is to use the from/to dataset as a translation table.

This is not a trivial problem, by the way; it's quite a difficult one when you have a lot of possible changes.  You're also going to get some false positives, where you change something that shouldn't have been changed, unless you have very well defined text (almost certainly you do not).

But ultimately you can attempt to do something like this:

```
data want;
  set have;  *your address dataset;
  do _n_ = 1 to nobs_trans;
    set trans point=_n_ nobs=nobs_trans;  *your from/to dataset;
    address = tranwrd(address,from,to);
  end;
run;
```

That's not exactly correct, but it's the skeleton of what you want to do.  It's also not at all *fast*; you'll want to do something faster likely, and if you want to do that you need to do some research on alternate approaches to this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you choose, in part, depends on the number of addresses being processed and number of possible replacements.

Instead of looping over potential replacements, considering looping over the words of the original text.

Essentially:

- For each word of address
- Lookup word for replacement
- Combine word/replacement-word back into transformed address

The for each process has several possibilities

- scan
- prxmatch/prxnext

The lookup process has many, many possibilities

- hash lookup
- custom format
- merge
- left join
- …

The combine process has multiple possibilities

- || concatenate operator
- catx function

Example of one implementation:

```
data addr; input; length address $100;
address = _infile_;
datalines;
Indonesia St 
Canada Av near from USA St
Japan St
Cingapure Av
;
run;
data map;
infile datalines;
input source $ destin $;
datalines;
St Street
Av Avenue
;
run;

data want;
  if 0 then set map;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash lookup(dataset: 'map');
    lookup.defineKey('source');
    lookup.defineData('source', 'destin');
    lookup.defineDone();
  end;

  set addr end=lastrecord;

  length altaddr $100;

  do index = 1 to countw(address);
    word = scan(address,index);

    if length(word) <= lengthm(source) then do;

      if 0 = lookup.find(key:trim(word))
        then altaddr = catx(' ', altaddr, destin);
        else altaddr = catx(' ', altaddr, word);

    end;
    else
      altaddr = catx(' ', altaddr, word);
  end;

  * address = altaddr;

  drop source destin index word;
run;
```